# finding an accurate Xpath for Google Sheets ImportXML

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets-formula

So, I'm trying to use the ImportXML function in Google sheets to scrape some data from a website (https://www.cargurus.com/Cars/m-Bob-Johnson-Certified-Collection-sp402449), and I'm having trouble finding a path that works. This is the section I'm looking to pull.
[image: Section of filter results]

I've tried using Chromes Inspect Element and using Copy X-path, Which gives me
`//*[@id="ratingFilter_ContainerId"]/div`
and returns #NA

I've used a Chrome plug-in called Scraper, which gives me `//div[13]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/label` and returns #NA

I've even tried going through the code and making as direct a path as I could from scratch and came up with `//body/div[1]/div[1]/main/div[1]/div[1]/div[11]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div[13]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div`
which also return #NA

So any tips for finding an accurate XPath would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The expression

```
//*[@id="ratingFilter_ContainerId"]
```

executed on a fetched document selects a `div` element two levels above the one you show.
When extended by another step subexpression:

```
//*[@id="ratingFilter_ContainerId"]/div
```

it selects the `div` which contains the 'Deal Ratings' caption with the '(clear)' link at the right side, *and* the options list you need.

What you are interested in is rather

```
$fetched-document/descendant::div[@id="ratingFilter_OptionListContainer"]
```

**EDIT**

BTW, are you sure you fetch the page properly? When I load it into my browser, the page seems to load some additional data, which is noted with a 'Loading listings...' splash. Maybe you're trying to execute your query on an incomplete page...?